# Floor sum function

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In order to calculate the number of pair $(a,b)$ such that $a,b \in \{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ and $a\mid b$, I want to calculate:
$$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lfloor n/i \rfloor$$

Is there any (mathematical) way to calculate above function for example for $n=10^{100}$?

Comment: Various formulae here: https://oeis.org/A006218

Comment: Probably not, but there are certainly good estimates and bounds.

Comment: The most obvious upper bound is $n\log (n+1).$

Comment: According to OEIS is $n \log(n) + (2 \gamma - 1) n - 4 \sqrt n - 1 \le f(n) \le n \log(n) + (2 \gamma - 1) n + 4 \sqrt n$

Comment: For accurate value, there’s no algorithm below $\mathcal o(n^{1/3})$ AFAIK.